# how can i download a area map and use offline in android application

Tags: android

I am developing a android app. and I want a particular area map which I can add in my app and use it offline navigation.
How can it be possible?

Is there any code for this?
http://lifehacker.com/5819742/google-maps-for-android-labs-add-offline-caching-scale-and-measuring-tools
this link is not good.
or if it possible then please help me.